# SAS, plot title

Tags: sas, title

How can I make the title to be "var1=e and var=b", suppose it is a repeat procedure (cannot hardcode).

```
  data test1;
    input y x var1$ var2$ key$;
    datalines;
    1  2 e b eb
    2  4 e b eb
    3  6 e b eb
    4  1 e b eb
    5  2 e b eb
    6  3 e b eb
    ;
    run;

proc sgplot data=test1 ;
series x=x y=y ;
title "I cannot make the title dynamic";
run;
```

Comment: Are you doing this for all unique values of a Var1 & Var2? If so, you need a BY statement and then you can control the titles with a BYVAL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read the values of VAR1 and VAR2 into a macro and then use that macro in the title.

```
proc sql noprint;
select var1, var2
   into :var1 trimmed, :var2 trimmed
   from test1(obs=1);
quit;

proc sgplot data=test1 ;
series x=x y=y ;
title "VAR1=&var1 and VAR2=&var2";
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The special title tokens `#BYVAR<n>` and `#BYVAL<n>` get replaced by the n-th by variable name and it's current grouping value.  This replacement occurs automatically as part of `by` group processing in procedures that produce output.

This example demonstrates how to turn off default by-lines and use the special tokens to produce the desired narrative in the output titles.

```
data cars;
  Wheels = 4;
  set sashelp.cars;
run;

options nobyline;
title "#byvar1=#byval1 and #byvar2=#byval2";

proc sgplot data=cars;
  by wheels make;
  vbar model / response=horsepower nostatlabel;
run;

options byline;
title;
```